# Codesys opc ua connection

Tags: opc-ua, read-write, codesys

I wanted to read and write data in codesys with the help of codesys opc ua and ua expert client. I wanted to generate certificate for the opc ua server and i went through the instructions present in https://help.codesys.com/api-content/2/codesys/3.5.14.0/en/_cds_runtime_opc_ua_server/.

I am using codesys sp16 and after installing security agent, i am unable to find devices tab in the  security screen tab. I am able to see only 2 options in the security screen tab.

How can i generate the certificate and get connected to the ua expert client?[Security screen tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kcTfp.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to start Control Win PLC first. Then you will see Divices tab.